# How do I change the targeted .NET 4.0 Framework to version 3.5 in an existing VS 2010 EXPRESS project?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.1, .net, vb.net

I am upgrading from ArcGIS desktop 10.0 to 10.1 and I have a bunch of addins developed in VS 2008 Express using ArcObjects 10.0.  I would like to upgrade everything **to 10.1 using VS 2010 Express**.  I understand that for ArcGIS Desktop [**.NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 is still required.**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.1/index.html#//01510000006n000000)

I converted my first existing addin to 10.1 in VS 2010 Express but it seems to be targeting .Net 4.0. I only found instructions on changing the target version in full version of VS but I can't find this feature in the Express edition.  Can someone shed some light on this?

EDIT:  I am adding a screenshot from Project -> Project Properties -> Application to show where I would expect to change the Target Framework but I don't see where it could be changed.
[image]

**EDIT 2:** I found an option to change Target Framework (All Configurations) under **Project -> Project Properties -> Compile -> Advanced Compile Options -> Target Framework (All Configurations)**

Can someone confirm that his is where I change the target framework in the 2010 Express edition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **Visual C# 2010 Express**:

  Project -> Project Properties -> Application -> Target Framework
- **VB.NET 2010 Express**: (thanks Jakub)

  Project -> Project Properties -> Compile -> Advanced Compile Options -> Target Framework
  (All Configurations)

Comment: This option "Target Framework" in Application is not listed in v10 express.

Comment: Thanks.  I found similar information but There is no "Target Framework" on the application tab in 2010 Express.

Comment: @artwork21  - Can I change it in Project -> Project Properties -> Compile -> Advanced Compile Options -> Target Framework (All Configurations) ?

Comment: @Jakub, Yes looks like you found it.

Comment: Thanks mate! If it doesn't work I will be back here asking more questions.

Comment: Not sure why it isn't showing up for you guys but that's where it was for me. Express by default tends to hide certain options but I couldn't find which option is responsible for hiding it.

Comment: @blah238, Are you using express v12 or v10?  Looks msdn article says the option is on the New Project dialog box, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398202.aspx, for v12

Comment: Visual C# 2010 Express. Maybe the VB.NET Express version is different?

Comment: @blah238, Yes VB.NET v10 Express is different, thx!

Comment: Updated answer to clarify the different locations for future readers.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you could try is opening the .vbproj or .csproj file in a text editor and changing this tag:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

TO

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Then save the file in the text editor.

Comment: I advise not to do this, because this will not modify references to .NET Framework core assemblies to .3.5.