# How to run a 2.0 ESRI DLL in a 4.0 Addin application

Tags: arcobjects, .net, framework

We have a complex set of operations running as Add-in's and services that span both ArcMap, ArcServer, and ArcGIS Explorer for Desktop.  Currently we are compiling everything under .NET 3.5 but we may need to move to .NET 4.0 to resolve an issue.

All of our code uses ProgressHelper from Explorer for Desktop 10.1 which is strictly a 2.0 framework applicaiton.  Normally I'd add the  command to the config file but the Add-In's are under ESRI control, not the .NET framework.

Is there a way to modify the ESRI configuration files so that the .NET framework knows that 4.0 is the supportedRuntime environment and allows me to load the 2.0 framework DLL?

As a testing note: ArcMap does have it's own configuration file and in that I do have the Startup section defined for both the 2.0 framework and the 4.0 framework.

Comment: Because .NET is (mostly) backwards-compatible, I think this should "just work". Have you tried it? See also: [How do I change the targeted .NET 4.0 Framework to version 3.5 in an existing VS 2010 EXPRESS project?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/48980/753)

Comment: It WOULD seem simple...but then we ARE talking ESRI.  I set the runtime for 4.0 but when I go to use the 2.0 dll it throws an internal exception when it call get_window which I assume is where it creates the window and displays it.